# Compilation errors for libplist on OS X Lion: string.h not found

Tags: c++, c, osx-lion

I'm trying to compile [Clementine](http://code.google.com/p/clementine-player/wiki/CompilingFromSourceMac) for OS X. Midway through the process of compiling dependencies, during libplist-1.3, I'm getting an error that the compiler cannot find string.h, assert.h, etc. Then a slew of errors follow.

I'm unsure why this would be the case. I'm not very experienced in working with larger C projects and would appreciate any direction in finding out why this is happening. I've definitely installed the Xcode command line tools and made sure they're up to date. Also, the standard files are in `/usr/include`.

Output after running `make` per build instructions:

```
cd libplist-1.3/build && PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/Users/dan/projects/sandbox/target/lib/pkgconfig cmake .. -DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES=x86_64 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/Users/dan/projects/sandbox/target -DQT_HEADERS_DIR=/Users/dan/projects/sandbox/target/include/ -DQT_LIBRARY_DIR=/Users/dan/projects/sandbox/target/bin -DENABLE_PYTHON=OFF
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    QT_HEADERS_DIR
    QT_LIBRARY_DIR


-- Build files have been written to: /Users/dan/projects/sandbox/clementine-dep/macosx/libplist-1.3/build
cd libplist-1.3/build && PATH=/Users/dan/projects/sandbox/target/bin:$PATH make -j2
[ 12%] [ 12%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/plist.dir/plist.c.o
Building C object src/CMakeFiles/plist.dir/bplist.c.o
/Users/dan/projects/sandbox/clementine-dep/macosx/libplist-1.3/src/plist.c:23:20: error: string.h: No such file or directory
/Users/dan/projects/sandbox/clementine-dep/macosx/libplist-1.3/src/plist.c:24:20: error: assert.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /Users/dan/projects/sandbox/clementine-dep/macosx/libplist-1.3/src/plist.h:25,
                 from /Users/dan/projects/sandbox/clementine-dep/macosx/libplist-1.3/src/plist.c:25:
/Users/dan/projects/sandbox/clementine-dep/macosx/libplist-1.3/include/plist/plist.h:48:20: error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
/Users/dan/projects/sandbox/clementine-dep/macosx/libplist-1.3/include/plist/plist.h:52:23: error: sys/types.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /Users/dan/projects/sandbox/clementine-dep/macosx/libplist-1.3/src/plist.h:25,
                 from /Users/dan/projects/sandbox/clementine-dep/macosx/libplist-1.3/src/plist.c:25:
/Users/dan/projects/sandbox/clementine-dep/macosx/libplist-1.3/include/plist/plist.h:128: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘val’
/Users/dan/projects/sandbox/clementine-dep/macosx/libplist-1.3/include/plist/plist.h:137: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘val’
/Users/dan/projects/sandbox/clementine-dep/macosx/libplist-1.3/include/plist/plist.h:156: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘uint64_t’
```

.. and many more

**Update:**

When removing the -j2 flag, libplist builds successfully. Now I am getting a new error down the line:

```
Scanning dependencies of target libproxy
[ 54%] Building CXX object libproxy/CMakeFiles/libproxy.dir/extension_config.cpp.o
[ 57%] Building CXX object libproxy/CMakeFiles/libproxy.dir/extension_pacrunner.cpp.o
[ 60%] Building CXX object libproxy/CMakeFiles/libproxy.dir/extension_wpad.cpp.o
[ 63%] Building CXX object libproxy/CMakeFiles/libproxy.dir/proxy.cpp.o
/Users/dan/projects/sandbox/clementine-deps/macosx/libproxy-0.4.7/libproxy/proxy.cpp:433:15: error: use of undeclared identifier
      'strdup'; did you mean 'strcmp'?
```

Comment: Have you tried compiling with `make` instead of `make -j 2`? Sometimes the compile order can get screwed up (this is explicitly stated in the package site you linked)

Comment: That worked! But now I get a new error in a different library..

Comment: According to `man strdup`, this function should be declared in `string.h`. Check to make sure there is a declaration.  Also, what compiler are you invoking by calling make?  Is it properly set to gcc/g++ ?  Finally, when you run into these types of errors, I find it very useful to write quick programs to check if I can use the functions causing problems.  If I can use it, then there is either a problem in the package source or build program.  Lucky for you, it's open source so you can fix it and notify the maintainer! Yay!

Comment: It seems that in my example it's defined in <cstring>. I created a sample program that includes cstring and calls strdup(""), which works. I also tried it with gcc/c++/clang/clang++. Could it be finding a <cstring> that isn't string.h?

Answer (score 1):

Partially copied from the comments:

Try compiling with `make` instead of `make -j 2`. Sometimes the compile order can get screwed up and this is explicitly mentioned in the package site you linked to.

As for the issues with `strdup`, the function is declared in string.h for C and `cstring` for C++. If the package is built correctly and doesn't create duplicate headers or try to use headers from non-standard locations, then starting from a **completely fresh** build might fix your problem.

If that doesn't work, you need to go through the `cmake` logs and look for directories in the include paths which may have `string.h` or `cstring` in them and might get used instead the default one. If this is the case, you should definitely notify the maintainer and figure out if simply removing these files or include path is an appropriate fix.

Beyond that I think you'll have to get in touch with the package maintainer through their site.

Good luck!